# Determining number of times part of loop has run

Tags: r, loops

I have this R code below. However, where i have put i in dy1,dy2 and in the loop I actually want this to be a measure of the amount of times this bit of the loop has run i.e. i in dy1 and line 9 should both be a measure of how many times line 9 has run while i in dy2 and line 11 should be a measure of how many times line 11 has run. Any ideas how I might do this?

```
s<-50
s2<-60
dy1<-s*exp(-i/s)
dy2<-s2*exp(-i/s2)
y <- c(0)
y <- c(0)
for (i in 1:150){
  if (dy1>dy2){
    y[length(y)+1] <- y[lenth(y)]+4*((s*(1-exp(-(i+1)/s)))-(s*(1-exp(-i/s)))) 
  } else {
    y[length(y)+1]=y[length(y)]+((s2*(1-exp(-(i+1)/s2)))-(s*(1-exp(-i/s)))) 
  } 
} 
y
```

Comment: Before the `for` loop initialize two counters, say, `m` and `n` to zero. In the loop, just before line 9 increment `m <- m + 1` and the same for `n` just before line 11.

Comment: That's great, thanks!

Comment: This code probably isn't working as intended. Line 9 will either always run or never run because `dy1` and `dy2` are constant. If you want them to vary by iteration you should do `dy1 <- function(i) s*exp(-i/s)` and similar for `dy2`

Comment: Thanks, I thought this might be happening. Should I use this code though? dy1 <- function(m) s*exp(-m/s) and dy2<- function(n) s*exp(-n/s) ,as I want dy1 to vary based on m and dy2 to vary based on n, and put this outside the loop? I tried this and got error message:Error in dy1 > dy2 : 
  comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types.